# Assistance with dataTables not processing my table - Laravel & Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables

I am trying to get dataTables to process my table in Laravel using an ajax script, I have no pages of search function.
'datatables.min.js' pulls through in chrome dev sources from CDN and I know my ajax is working because other scripts work fine on the page.

I am using some basic custom CSS on the table via a custom.css file, but I was under the impression that is fine.

**My controller code.**

```
 // FETCH ALL AJAX REQUEST
    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $vehicles = Vehicle::all(); //Could be model or controller...

        $output = '';
        if ($vehicles->count() > 0) {
            $output .= '<table #"showAll" class="veh-table table table-striped table-sm text-center align-middle" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="tbl-head">ID</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Image</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Make</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Model</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Derivative</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Powertrain</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Transmission</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Fuel Type</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Model Year</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head"><i class="bi-gear-fill h5"></i></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
            foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
                $output .= '<tr class="tbl exp_tbl">
                    <td>'.$vehicle->id.'</td>
                    <td><img src="./storage/images/'.$vehicle->image.'"  class="img-thumbnail justify-content-sm-center"></td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->make.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->model_name.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->version.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->powertrain.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->trans.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->fuel.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->model_year.'</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/edit" id="' . $vehicle->id . '" class="text-success mx-2 editIcon" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editVehicleModal"><i class="bi-pencil-square h6"></i></a>

                        <a href="#" id="' . $vehicle->id .'" class="text-danger mx-1 delete-icon"><i class="bi-trash h6"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
            }
            $output .= '</tbody></table>';
            echo $output;
        } else {
            echo '<h1 class="text-center text-secondary my-5">No vehicles in the database!</h1>';
        }
    }
```

**The function from my html.**

```
...
$(function() {
...
                // SHOW ALL VEHICLES AJAX REQUEST
                fetchAllVehicles();
                function fetchAllVehicles(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '{{route('fetchAll')}}',
                        method: 'GET',
                        success: function(res){
                            $("#show_all_vehicles").html(res);
                            $("#showAll").DataTable({
                                order: [ 0, "desc" ]
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
...
             }
...
```

I have tried adding

```
{
dataType: 'json',
processData: true, // & false...
serverSide: false, // & true...
}
```

Please let me know if I haven't included some needed information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$output .= '<table #"showAll"....
```

to

```
$output .= '<table id="showAll"....
```

and let me know if that works

Comment: I have fixed that typo and still no joy I'm afraid. Thank you anyway.
I have also tried changing the id to 'table'.

Comment: Where do you have defined 'show_all_vehicles'?